# How to kill the process spawned by a during the execution of subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have a tiny `pytest` fixture which sets up the backend server prior to the test run.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def server():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'runserver.sh'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    yield
    p.kill()
```

`runserver.sh` starts a flask server.

The fixture is supposed to kill the server process when the test run has terminated.
The problem with my solution is that it properly kills the blocking process with the Flask server, but it does not kill the `python` process spawned during its execution.

I also tried this:

```py
pgid = os.getpgid(p.pid)
os.killpg(pgid, 9)
```

This does kill the `python` process started by my subprocess, but it also kills the `python` that is executing the test run...

Any ideas on clever ways that can be used to kill the child `python` process?

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but instead of killing your process, you could kindly ask it to die and kill all of its children. Since it is a web server, maybe there could be a "shutdown" endpoint.

Comment: I have found a most stupid yet effective way to solve this problem - in fixture teardown, I iterate over all processes in the system, find the one called `python` (that's where flask lives) and kill that process by PID. Interestingly, `psutil` only finds one process named `python`.

Comment: Be aware that wrapping this in ``bash`` might make it a bash problem. You are killing the bash script, not the server it spawned. Depending on what the script actually does, the signal may-or-may-not be forwarded properly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi

The script is very simple. It actually only goes to the directory with the server, activates venv and executes `python -m flask run`.

Comment: @Aemilius You might want to directly invoke the venv then. ``/path/to/venv/bin/python -m flask run`` will save you the wrapper.